# Filtering pandas based on value tuples for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a large dataframe with the following format:

```
user1    user2 +++++ other columns ++++++
---------------
Alice    Carol +++++ other columns ++++++
Alice    Bob   +++++ other columns ++++++
Bob      Carol +++++ other columns ++++++
Alice    Carol +++++ other columns ++++++
```

And I have a separate text file that contains

```
Alice,Bob
Bob,Carol
```

How do I get the output

```
user1    user2 +++++ other columns ++++++
---------------
Alice    Carol   +++++ other columns ++++++
Bob      Carol   +++++ other columns ++++++
Alice    Carol   +++++ other columns ++++++
```

without having to use df.iterrows() (since that will be slow)?

EDIT:
I've also tried merge. It now works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Alice','Alice','Bob','Alice'],'b':['Carol','Bob','Carol','Carol']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':['Alice','Bob'],'b':['Carol','Carol']})
pd.merge(df,df2,on=['a','b'])
```

resulted in

```
       a      b
0  Alice  Carol
1  Alice  Carol
2    Bob  Carol
```

Comment: Merge on the two columns.

Comment: Please provide more details if merge does not work: show your code, what error did you get?

Comment: Hi @IanS edited again to show details

Comment: Oh found my mistake. The merge should be on both 'a' and 'b'. My bad.